# Building with new Qt 5.9 for Android failed

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qtquick2, android-sdk-tools

I've just installed Qt 5.9 - `Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.1 for Android armv7)`

Then I've downloaded and installed all the Android packages:
[image: Android packages]

Then I've created new Qt Quick application project in Qt Creator. 
But while building the project i get some strange error:

```
22:02:34: Starting: "D:\Qt\Qt5.9\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=D:/source/build-Ble-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_1_for_Android_armv7-Debug/android-build" install
      0 [main] sh 4200 sync_with_child: child 4856(0x1A0) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
     16 [main] sh 4200 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
Makefile:884: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_target] Error 129
```

It looks that building failed on some shell script but I don't know where is it. As I see it related to installing process. Compiling and linking the code finished without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem has found. I have firmware uploading utility for AVR called `AVRDude`. It looks that while installing `AVRDude` added itself to the `PATH` environment and so Qt takes `sh` and all other bash tools from this folder.

Removing `AVRDude` from `PATH` and rebuilding the projects solved the problem.